# Fit an arbitrary PDF

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a way to fit several arbitrary discrete distributions to another discrete distribution using maximum likelihood, but I'm having trouble finding a function to do this in `numpy` or `scipy`. I'm ok with using another library, so long as

- it's in C++ or Python
- it is designed specifically for fitting (trying to avoid GUIs and massive packages)

The fitted distributions come from toy Monte Carlo, so they are represented by a series of ordered pairs.

Comment: You will probably need to clarify two things to get a definitive answer to your question: (1) what distribution are you interested in, specifically, and for what purpose; and (2) whether this is purely a programming or language-related issue. In the latter case, this question would be better suited to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I clarified a bit. The distributions are derived from toy models. As for why I posted the question here: I'm open to any mathematical recasting of the problem; and advice as to how to best perform the fit is welcome. But if you feel that it's more appropriate on SO, I have no issue with migration.

Comment: Shep, this is probably the right site for such a question, but it lacks details needed to come up with an answer. Could you please tell us more about where these "arbitrary discrete distributions" come from, why you're trying to fit them to some (family) of distributions, what this family is specifically, and why you believe ML is the right approach.

Comment: the distributions are histograms that summarize data from an experiment (particle collider, to be exact), we have data distributions, and Monte Carlo distributions corresponding to various theories. Sometimes there's not a lot of entries in a given histogram, and we generally use ML for low statistics.

Comment: I really can't tell you much about the family of distributions: we make histograms of dozens of quantities, most of which are only used because they work well to discriminate between various physical processes.

Comment: For a start, it sounds like you do *not* have discrete distributions, but only discrete summaries of variables that probably should be modeled with continuous distributions. But what is your analytical objective: are you, for instance, trying to determine which of the theories provides the best fit for the data? If so, it will be important to understand how those theories model the data, because some analog of number of (free) parameters would likely play an important role in assessing the fits.

Comment: It's true that the distributions aren't actually discrete, but they also aren't necessarily easy to parameterize: they are often things like ANN or BDT outputs, or what would be a decaying exponential, but isn't because our reconstruction software mangles the distribution in some regions. We've always dealt with this using discrete summaries. If this approach is horribly flawed, that would also be good to know, but in the past it's been considered good enough.

Comment: As for the objective: different processes happen with different frequencies, so we fit normalized distributions to the data and use the coefficients to extract the frequency.